# How to use the right click context menu to send files to new folder?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-management, context-menu

Here is my issue:
I'm in a folder full of different files. I see a number of files I'd like to group together. I can select them, "right click -> send to -> *list of programs/operations*". In that list of programs/operations there is a "Compressed (zipped) folder" option.

My question is: Is there a way to send these files to an uncompressed new folder?

It's possible to edit the "send to" list but I haven't been able to find a way to add "create new (uncompressed) folder" to that list. Perhaps using a .cmd file would work?

Comment: While theoretically this sounds like a good idea, you can just as easily select the files, press Ctrl+C to copy them, and then create a new folder to paste them in. This also has the flexibility of allowing you to place that new folder wherever you want before you copy the files, whereas "send to" (at least for me) automatically creates that folder in the same directory.

Comment: Type in Start - Run `shell:sendto`. Create shortcuts to programs or folders in the folder to have them appear on sendto menu. Remember it is a MOVE if source and destination are on the same drive (as it simulates drag drop rules). Hold down control to force a copy.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! My question has been answered by Mendelg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a context menu to Copy or to Move content to a folder.

save the following as a file with `.reg` extension and run it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Copy To folder
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{C2FBB630-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}]

; Move To folder
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}]
```

[This will be added to the context menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW3zA.png)

If you want later to remove the context menu, save the following as a file with `.reg` extension and run it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Copy To folder
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{C2FBB630-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}]

; Move To folder
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}]
```

[credit to this forum](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/29141-add-copy-folder-move-folder-context-menu-windows-10-a.html)

---

If you want to edit the "Send to" context menu:

type <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. under the Run dialog type `shell:sendto` click "OK".

In that directory, you can add a shortcut to a folder you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't mind installing a 3rd-party utility (or is already using this one), [TeraCopy](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy) has an option (included in the free version) to add a context menu item which does exactly that. It works like a charm.

Here's an example:

[image: Demo]

This is better than the "Move to folder" option because it immediately creates the folder and starts a rename operation as opposed to opening the ancient folder browse dialog.

Disclaimer: I'm *not* affiliated with TeraCopy in any way but I've been using it for a long time and funny enough, I always thought that option was part of Windows 10 and came with one of the updates. I never realized it belonged to a 3rd party utility until it went missing today and left me scratching my head trying to find out what happened to that "Windows feature" that no one else seems to have seen before.