# Move multiple selected files to new folder from context menu

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, context-menu, send-to

I'm trying to add a SendTo option which would work the same way the "Compressed (zipped) folder" SendTo option works, but instead *moves* the selected files and folders to a *new folder* instead:

1. Select files and/or folders in Windows Explorer
2. Right click one of the selected items or hit the menu key on the keyboard
3. Hover over Send to and click on a new option "New folder"
4. The selected items are moved to a new folder in the current directory.

Some care might be needed regarding the name of the new folder so that it doesn't collide with an already existing one.

Optionally, it would be nice if the folder inherited the name of one of the files (ideally the one right-clicked) and furthermore it would also be nice, but not necessary, if once the folder is created and the files moved into it if the folder's name can be immediately modified without further action, just like the "Compressed (zipped) folder" SendTo option works.

I've looked into doing this on my own and found the following:

- [How to use the right click context menu to send files to new folder?](https://superuser.com/q/1563627)

This works but introduces unnecessary steps by displaying a new window and the folder needing to be first created by hand and then selected.

- [Application that will move file to new folder with file's name](https://superuser.com/q/536116)

This almost does the trick, but seems to only work with a single file. I've tried modifying it to use `%*` instead of `%1` in the move command, but it seems the script only receives a single parameter? I'm not too sure as I don't have much experience with this scripting language.

- I'm also aware of Shell Extensions however I have no idea how these work.

I am using Windows 10, but I wouldn't expect the solution to be specific to this version though I could be wrong. Also if a solution is found but doesn't use the SendTo feature but can still be added in the contextual menu, that's fine for me.

Any help with this would be appreciated :)

EDIT: changed `$1` and `$*` to `%1` and `%*` (was just a typo, the issue still stands)

EDIT2: I searched a bit more on my own today and found this ["sendto" all selected files into a folder](https://superuser.com/q/1711537/1704555) which is actually what I was looking for. It's weird this was so difficult to find but oh well.

Comment: `This almost does the trick, but seems to only work with a single file. I've tried modifying it to use $* instead of $1` .. the link you point to is batch.  `$*` and `$1` are not batch.  You say `this scripting language` .. which one do you think that you are using?  Also, one doesn't MOVE a folder or file to a compressed volume (under the hood).  One ADDS the file or folder and then deletes the original.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Indeed there was a typo in the post, now fixed. As for your second point I don't see how that's relevant considering I specifically say in the first sentence: work the same way the "Compressed (zipped) folder" SendTo option works, **but instead _moves_ the selected files and folders to a new folder"**.
Notice the combination of the words "instead" and "move".

Comment: @DarkDiamond it does, as I answered here https://superuser.com/a/1728347/1704555

Comment: @wisebane Answers aren't links to other answers - please see [answering](https://superuser.com/help/answering) in the help section. If the [linked to answer](https://superuser.com/a/1711547/529800) is the answer to this question, this question should be closed as a [duplicate](https://superuser.com/q/1711537/529800).

Comment: @wisebane first of all.. its all cool!  I am here to help YOU and not start a war.  Second of all .. you don't see how my question about how you were going about it is relevant? .. that makes no sense to me.  I have written at least 30 windows shell extensions in c/c++.  I have tweaked the shell since windows 95 with everything from batch to python to c++.  My questions are sound even if you don't understand their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this can be added to the *Send to* context menu since these are physical shortcuts contained within `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`, however *Copy to folder...* and *Move to folder...* can be added to the main context menu via:

*General FYI: this isn't an elegant solution, as it requires navigating through the directory tree, with no ability to efficiently open a nested directory or paste a directory path*

- **[GUI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/windows-registry-advanced-users):**

  1. <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → *Open:* `RegEdit` → *OK*
  2. Click on the Address Bar → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (x2) → Paste path below → <kbd>Enter</kbd>

     ```cmd
     HKCR\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
     ```
  3. Right-click on `ContextMenuHandlers` → *New* → *Key* → `CopyTo`

     1. Right-click on `(Default)` → *Modify...*
     2. *Value data:* `{C2FBB630-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}` → *OK*
  4. Right-click on `ContextMenuHandlers` → *New* → *Key* → `MoveTo`

     1. Right-click on `(Default)` → *Modify...*
     2. *Value data:* `{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}` → *OK*
- **[CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add):**

  ```cmd
  # Copy to:
    Reg Add "HKCR\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\CopyTo" /t REG_SZ /d "{C2FBB630-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}"

  # Move to:
    Reg Add "HKCR\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\MoveTo" /t REG_SZ /d "{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}"
  ```

Comment: After thinking about this futher, for the _Send to_ context menu, or as an entry to the main context menus, a `.vbs`, or possibly a `.cmd`/`.ps1`, script could be configured so that when it's selected from the context menu a box for the folder path wanted is shown with _OK_ / _Cancel_ buttons. I don't have the time to create this, but can begin working on it when I have time around August-ish.

Comment: This is the exact same solution provided [here](https://superuser.com/q/1563627/1704555) which is also the first link in my post.

Comment: @wisebane Similar, not the same.